# selenium webdriver isDisplayed() returns true when element is not visible

Tags: java, selenium, find, webdriver

I have elements in a drop down list in a collapsing side bar.  There are two top-level items in the side bar.  When you click one, the contents beneath it are revealed.

I am testing a bookmark, so I hit the bookmark with driver.get() and the page loads.  In the side bar, the appropriate top-level item should be selected and the content beneath should be revealed, and the selected lower-level item should be highlighted.  So I am trying to test whether the lower-level (selected) item is indeed visible, using isDisplayed().

However what I see is that isDisplayed() returns true, even when the wrong top level item is expanded, and in fact the selected item is not displayed.  Here is an example...

Beers

- Lager

  Ale

  Stout

Whiskeys

- Bourbon

  Rye

  Scotch

I hit the bookmark to 'Rye', but the items under 'Beers' are displayed (expanded) while the items under 'Whiskeys' are not (they are collapsed).  Yet Rye.isDisplayed() is returning true.  So my test is missing the bug that the items under Whiskey are not correctly expanded.

I can use getLocation() in a sort of lame way, but am looking for something a little more airtight.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got a URL (or HTML code) so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Hmm, don't have URL as it is on a development site.  I was wondering if other folks had experienced this an might have a more sturdy work around?  Not to confuse the point, but I have noticed that I sometimes have just the opposite problem when trying to click elements in a windows VM on IE.  I look at the screen and I can see that the element is visible, but I get an 'Can't Click a non-visible element' error.   This is just the opposite, the element is clearly not visible, but isDisplayed() does not seem to catch that.

Comment: Yeah, I see. But even to report a bug, we have to be able to reproduce it. Can you extract some of the HTML of the page with this odd behavior maintained?

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help.  I think I will live with it for the moment.  If I can pull out the html and park it in a separate doc and test that, I will then post it.  Thanks.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.isDisplayed() cannot be relied upon.